# Does "indio" mean Indian, indigene, and Hindu?

Tags: religión, geografía, polisemia

I have heard that *indio* is used in Spanish to mean Indian, indigene, and Hindu.

Are all three meanings correct?

Comment: "Indian" has multiple meanings in English, too... "Native American," "Indian" (one from India), or "Hindu" (broadly speaking--as most Hindus come from in or near India)

Comment: @Flimzy I have never encountered "Indian" in English being used as a synonym for Hindu.

Comment: What do you mean by the word "indigene"?

Answer (score 5):

The word *"**indio**"* referrs to someone from either the East Indies or the West Indies but contemporaneously usually refers to either an Indian national (someone from India or otherwise related to the Indian subcontinent) or someone ethnically related to the peoples who lived in the Americas before Columbus.  I don't know about other parts of the Spanish-speaking world, but at least in Colombia *"indio"* is also a pejorative for someone deemed to be less educated or from a lesser cultural level (regardless of ethnic background).

The word *"**indígena**"* would roughly translate in English to native, aboriginal or indigenous, so it could be applied to a Lapp (a Same) in Finland, an Australian aboriginal, or to an *indio* from the Americas.  It could also be extended to a white blonde person German in Germany, although this meaning is rare.  Technically correct but rare.  In the Americas, many people say *"indígena"* instead of *"indio"* to avoid the other two meanings of *"indio"* (someone from India or the insult).  As with any other ethnically related word, some people adopt it with pride and some people will feel offended.

The word *"**hindú**"* correctly applies to either someone from historical Hindustan or a follower of Hinduism.  By extension, and to avoid the use of *"**indio**"* (to avoid confusion with native Americans or the pejorative meaning) it is also applied to nationals of India.  Most educated people will agree that *"hindú"* is incorrect when referring to just someone from India (unless related to Hindustan or Hinduism).

For avoiding confusion the word *"**hinduísta**"* refers to a follower of Hinduism regardless of ethnic or national identity.

Another related word is *"**amerindio**"* derived from *"indio americano"* which refers to someone indigenous to the Americas, avoiding any confusion with *"indio"* (and being more precise than *"indígena"*).  Also, while some people proudly adopt the exonym *"amerindio"* others may take it offensively.

So, in summary:

***indio:***

1. A Indian national or related to India
2. A Native American
3. [insult] an uncultured person

***indígena:***

1. Indigenous, aboriginal, native
2. [narrowly]: indigenous, aboriginal, or native of the Americas

***hindú:***

1. Someone related to Hindustan
2. A Hindu
3. [by extension]: an Indian national

Comment: Although the answer is perfectly correct it's important to asset that many people use the word "indio" on a familiar way to cover all previous meanings.

Comment: Not sure what all previous meanings are.  I would find hard to find someone using _«indio»_ to refer to a blond German in Germany or a white American converted to Hinduism.

Comment: Agree, however, on a familiar way you'll find more people using indio than hindú to refer to a natural from India, although hindú would be correct expression

Answer (score 0):

Although *indio* is often used as a polysemic word meaning Indian, indigene, or Hindu, in Spanish we have specific words for each of these:

- **Hindu → hindú**
- **Indian → indio**
- **indigene → indígena**

Hence, if using *indio* to refer to one of the above three meanings one must ensure the context is unambiguous.

**Note:** using *indio* for indigene sounds to me like some kind of insult. *Indio* is used sometimes in a pejorative way, when referring to south-americans.

Comment: Not complete: spanish "Indio" can mean both from America and from India. "Hindú" is a racial/religious reference where not all indians from India are included. Some may even take offense if you call them "Hindú".

Comment: Well, I often refer to those that follow hinduism as hinduists, that's how I difference them, not trying to be offensive, so probably is my way to understand it that makes me say that 'Hindú' is for 'Hindu', for me 'Hindú' is someone born or a citizen of India, and hinduist is someone that follows hinduism as a religion.

Comment: Yes, but it is not only how you refer to them, but how them can feel when one refers to them.

Comment: Well I searched mroe about 'Hindú' in RAE, and the definition doesn't get peorative meaning, it refers to citizens and religious both. So maybe I was not so wrong, and you are the frist to tell me that, maybe I'll e-mail them for a clarification.

Comment: Estando en una conversación con un colega, apareció el tema del significado delos términos Indio, Indígena e Hindú. Yo sabía que Indio puede ser usada de forma peyorativa, pero el insiste en que Hindú también es malsonante a oídos de un habitante de la India, ya que, según el, Hindú se refiere solamente a un grupo racial y religioso de ciudadanos de la India.

En el diccionario no se trata Hindú con un uso peyorativo, o exclusivamente racial o religioso, sino que también se indica que sirve para denominar a un ciudadano procedente de la India.

¿Nos podríais sacar de dudas?

Muchas gracias

Comment: It is not about "Hindú" having pejorative meaning, it is about some people being offended by it. It is the same as "kosovar". It is not pejorative, but some people in Kosovo may get offense if you call them kosovar (for the country) because they are not kosovar (in the ethnic sense).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are [confusing](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32966/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-indio-e-hind%C3%BA/32967) the terms *indio* and *hindú*:

- [*indio*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=indio) can refer to either Indians or Native Americans
- [*hindú*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=hind%C3%BA) can refer to either Indians* or Hindus

*Indio* is not to my knowledge used to refer to indigenous persons in general. The Spanish word for this is *indígena* or *aborigen*.

---

<sup>* Historically used to refer to persons from "Hindustan" (historical India, the Indian subcontinent): India, Pakistan, Bangladesh, Nepal, Sri Lanka, the Maldives, Bhutan.</sup>