# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "indio" e "hindú"?

Tags: sinónimos, religión, geografía, polisemia

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre *indio* e *hindú*? ¿Son sinónimos exactos?

Comment: Acabo de caer en la cuenta de que estás respondiendo a tu propia pregunta. Aunque es interesante (y completamente válido) para traer contenido interesante al stack, no sería mejor poner esta respuesta en la pregunta enlazada? Son demasiado similares. Se podría editar la pregunta para añadir la tuya (que es muy breve) si lo que querías era un pregunta en español. También es posible actualizar con lo que tienes aquí [tu respuesta en la otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32965/5481) o incluso postear más de una (puedes tener varias respuestas por pregunta, si son distintas)

Comment: @Diego I was considering that, but I wanted to make a more focused question on the difference between *Indio* and *hindú* specifically (the latter of which the asker doesn't mention at all), and given there are existing answers on the other question talking specifically about the asker's mention of "indigene" I thought editing it to change it to this question would be too different and against the author's intention (assuming they actually meant what they wrote and didn't just confuse "Indigenous American" with the strangely archaic term "indigene"). Hence making a (related) but different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente diagrama de Venn ilustra la intersección de los significados de estes términos relacionados:

[image: Venn diagram of terms in Spanish for Indian, Hindu, and Native American]

> #### DPD: [indio -dia.](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=indio)
>
> 1. ‘De la India’... Como gentilicio de la India es también admisible el uso de *hindú* (→ [hindú](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SIviwh20rD64XaLoUZ)) y de la variante *indo*, desusada en la lengua general, pero que pervive en el registro culto literario...
> 2. El término *indio* es también el gentilicio de las poblaciones aborígenes del continente americano... Es asimismo frecuente el uso del término *indígena*, debido en parte al matiz despectivo que ha adquirido la voz *indio* en algunos países de América... Son alternativas correctas los términos *amerindio* e *indoamericano*, de uso más restringido...

> #### DPD: [hindú](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=hind%C3%BA)
>
> 1. En sentido estricto significa ‘del hinduismo o que profesa el hinduismo (religión predominante en la India)’... El hecho de que la mayoría de la población de la India profese el hinduismo, junto con el deseo de evitar la ambigüedad del gentilicio *indio* (usado también para designar a los aborígenes del continente americano), explica que prácticamente desde su introducción al español en el último tercio del siglo xix se haya usado también esta voz para designar a los naturales de la India. Este uso extensivo de *hindú* es admisible en contextos en que no exista riesgo de confusión con su sentido estrictamente religioso... El plural preferido en la lengua culta es hindúes...
> 2. Posteriormente, y debido seguramente a la polisemia del término *hindú*, se creó para los sentidos específicamente religiosos el término *hinduista*...

También hay los gentilismos *indostanés, indostano, indostánico* que se usaba [históricamente](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hindostan%C3%A9s%22&lr=lang_es&tbs=lr:lang_1es,sbd:1&tbm=bks) para los nativos de Indostán. *Hindú* solía usarse así también, pero hoy en día refiere a los nacionales de India contemporáneo.

La palabra *hindú* **no** se refiere a la lengua *hindi*, pero *indostánico* sí.